# confusing about addEventListener

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I write a debounce function and want to display input using that function.

```
    let btn = document.querySelector('.firstScreen')
    let input = document.querySelector('input')

    function debounce(fn, time) {
        let timer = null
        return function(...args){
            if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                fn()
            }, time)
        }
    }

    function display(){
        btn.children[1].innerHTML=input.value
    }
```

it is not working when I write like this:

```
  document.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
        debounce(display, 2000)
    })
```

but working like this:

```
    document.addEventListener('keyup',debounce(display, 2000))
```

why?

Answer (score 1):

You return a function from the `debounce(display, 2000)` as you should. That function is not callable as a function so the first example is not using the returned function but only creating the function you are supposed to use

You COULD do

```
document.addEventListener('keyup',function(){ return debounce(display, 2000) })
```

which is a waste of code when you can do what you already determined works

```
document.addEventListener('keyup',debounce(display, 2000))
```